# How to enable tabs in a Popup window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, popup

When I click on a url in my page, it supposed to open a popup window with tabs view enabled, so that i can browse the pages in the same popup without going back to parent window.

I have tried the following code, but it just created the Popup without Tabbed view enabled.

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/', 'asdas', 'menubar=yes,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');" value="Open the window">
```

is there a way to enable tabbed view in a Popup Window using JavaScript or JQuery?

Comment: You can open new tab, for example. `window.open('your_url', '_blank');`

Comment: I have to open my first page in Popup only.. then afterwards i have to use tabs in the newly opened window :(

Comment: Javascript doesn't have any way of distinguishing opening windows and tabs.

Comment: in chrome, there an option to enable tabs 'Show as Tab' which enables the tabbed view... i.e. popup window becomes a normal browser window. Is it possible to do the same using Javascript or JQuery?